# inserting into data sourced combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

i am working on visual studio 2012 c# ...
i inserted values into the combox ...i took them from database...I WANT TO KNOW HOW CAN I ADD AN ITEM TO THE COMBOBOX  ...ill show u the code below:

Here this function to fill the combobox with names taken from a table in database containig name and id:

```
List<Lookup> fillCombo(string query, string column)
    {
        List<Lookup> lookups = new List<Lookup>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Lookup lookupobject = new Lookup();
                lookupobject.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                //if (reader["Name"] != DBNull.Value)
                lookupobject.Name = reader[column].ToString();

                lookups.Add(lookupobject);
            }


            conn.Close();
        }

        return lookups;
    }
```

then i call this function as follows:

```
lookups = fillCombo("select id,name from LookupDetails where LOOKUPID =  (select id from Lookup where Name = 'users')", "name");

        comboBox2.DataSource = lookups;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Comment: What isn't working? is this wpf/winforms? does `lookups` contain any values?

Comment: i cant add an item..i tried adding item using this command : comboBox2.Items.Insert(0, "");
 but it didnt work cz the data is binded ..so i want to know how to add data to the combobox ...and yes list contains list having objectes each object has username and id

Comment: You need to insert into `lookups`

Comment: @mhammadkassem. is it winforms application?

Comment: can u tell me how ? cz im kinda a beginner in c# please acn u write me the code?

Comment: @Sayse yes its a windows form app

Answer (score 0):

ComboxBox Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

You got the options of either modifying the `List<Lookup>` or by adding items into combox by iterating over the `List<Lookup>`.

Here is option to add items in combobox using foreach loop and insert item at 0 index of comboxbox:

```
lookups = fillCombo(@"select id,name from LookupDetails where LOOKUPID =  
                     (select id from Lookup where Name = 'users')", "name");

foreach(var obj in lookups)
     comboBox2.Items.Add(obj);

comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox2.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

Note: In the code mentioned in the question, `SqlDataReader` was never closed, I have modified it by including `using` statement. You don't have to close `SqlDataReader` or `SqlConnection` when you write these in `using` block:

```
List<Lookup> fillCombo(string query, string column)
{
    List<Lookup> lookups = new List<Lookup>();
    string sConstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConstring))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              Lookup lookupobject = new Lookup();
              lookupobject.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
              //if (reader["Name"] != DBNull.Value)
              lookupobject.Name = reader[column].ToString();
              lookups.Add(lookupobject);
            }
         }
     }        

    return lookups;
}
```